# Please help me identify this language (w/ image)

Tags: language-identification

I have a scan of a genealogical document (ca. 1895) from a Catholic church in Brodowe Łąki, Poland. I believe that the document pertains to the baptism of my great-grandmother, but I can't quite be sure until I know what it says. I showed the image to some Polish relatives, and they couldn't recognize any of the writing besides the names (my great-grandmother's name was Zofia Miecznikowska, but we have reason to believe she might have been baptised by the name Anna). We think the text might actually be written in Latin, but the handwriting is quite ornamental and difficult to read. Would anybody be able to decipher what this says, or even what language it's written in? The relevant paragraph is the one on the top right (the record numbered 41). (To see the image at full size, right-click and click "View Image.")[image: baptismal record of Anna Miecznikowska]

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Interesting question, but I cn't actually see the image or a link to an image. If this is a problem for any one else (it might just be my browser) could you update the question?

Comment: @DangerFourpence - Here's [the link to the image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3ToNr.jpg).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is Russian, the pre-1918 orthography.

It says that in the village of Brodowe Łąki on the 11th (23rd) of June 1895 came Walenty Miecznikowski, aged 45, a worker from Blenda, and in the presence of witnesses Franciszek Fonk, aged 40, and Jakob Fonk, aged 35, both land-tillers from Blenda, he presented a female baby, having said it was born the day before at 7 p.m. from his legal wife Franciszka, born Kierzynowska. During the holy baptism conducted that day the baby was given the name Anna, the god-parents being Jozef and Marijanna Borsy. This Act was signed by the Administrator of the Brodowe Łąki Parish and read to them. Signature: priest Michail Sawicki.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! This makes some sense, as I know that Brodowe Łąki is only about 10 miles from where my great-uncle said my great-grandmother was from, which was Myszyniec. I had forgotten that Masovia was part of Russia instead of Prussia by the time of Anna Miecznikowska's birth, so in retrospect, the Russian makes sense.